# How do I determine the minimum order amount for WooCommerce that won't receive points?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I'm creating a WooCommerce website using WordPress, aiming to award reward points for orders, but need to set a minimum order amount limit without a plugin. I don't know how to get reward points for lowest order. Please help some to resolve this issue.

*I have tried  get minimum order amount but don't know how to get reward points for limited order amount.*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {

    $minimum = 50; // Hier gibst du den Mindestbestellwert ein

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) { 
            if( is_cart() ) { 
                wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Der Mindestbestellwert beträgt %s pro Bestellung. Der aktuelle Bestellwert beträgt %s.' , // Text fuer Warenkorb 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
            ), 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Der Mindestbestellwert beträgt %s pro Bestellung. Der aktuelle Bestellwert beträgt %s.' , // Text fuer Kasse
                wc_price( $minimum ),
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
            ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Evgeniy Mikhalev do you work work with OP or know the problem statement, to remove a LOC? ` `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );`? I am curious to know this as to what made you remove that line?

Comment: anyways you can try to award reward points when the minimum order amount is met using custom logic to calculate and assign reward points.